# CSS only Square grid, 3 lines, responsive height, variable number of squares

Tags: css, responsive-design

I’ve been working on this for over 10 hours, searching the web for a solution, to no avail.

Here is the screen capture of the sketch:

[image]

I need to produce a grid layout with the following requirements:

- The whole thing is in a horizontal scrolling layout.
- Responsive in height, relative to its container (which is already responsive relative to body, using the Stretch-to-margin technic).
- 3 lines of equal height (33.333%)
- Composed of square images anchors

  - On mouse over: color overlay with white text
- The square images need to keep their proportion (reduce the height of the window, image width must scale down.
- The width of the whole layout must be dynamic, since the number of squares may vary.

I’ve seen tons of examples where the width is defined, and using the padding-top value to define the height. It would not work here since the Height is the defining value.

I will be posting again with updates tomorrow.

I’m kinda desperate. Thinking of taking up drinking (kidding).

Comment: Please post the HTML and CSS that you have tried

Comment: This might get you started - http://jsfiddle.net/y3XnM/

Comment: I’ve been thinking about it all night. This morning, I dived in a jsfiddle and produced this http://jsfiddle.net/CharlesKaki/wp3Va/9/ It works somehow with Safari, its OK with Firefox, don't know about IEs. What surprises me is that, when changing the height of the window, the width doesn't get updated live. You need to refresh. On load, the width is proportional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Question is Answered!

I finally used the "vh" unit, and applied it to HEIGHT and WIDTH of all the squares.

Goes something like this:

```
.c-squares{
    width:30vh;
    height:30vh;
    display:inline;
}
```

So clean, can’t believe I’ve never knew about "vh" unit.